# Override item subtotal

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I'm using an observer to override the checkout_cart_product_add_after in order to update a unit price of a product. The price comes from a third party system and it tailored for each customer. I can set the price as follows:

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
if ($item->getParentItem()) {
    $item = $item->getParentItem();
}

$specialPrice = $this->get_price($item->getsku(), $item->getQty());
$item->setCustomPrice($specialPrice);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($specialPrice);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

The product prices can technically be as many as 6 decimal places. I'm using the ET_Currency manager to set the display to 4 decimal places as that's the maximum it seems to allow. On small quantities it's not a problem but on large quantities it can be 30p - 40p out.

Can anyone advise how I can get this to 6 decimal places so the subtotals are more accurate?

Comment: Strangely I've followed suggestions on other posts and the mini basket shows the correct formatting now, as soon as I go to the cart it seems to update the record and change the precision so it becomes incorrect. Does going into the cart update all records?